# Python: Remove a button on click and restore in another click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wrote a gui program using Tkinter.

```
 from Tkinter import *     

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.resizable(0,0)
        self.lframe = Frame(self.root,width=300,height=200,bg="White",padx=0)
        self.lframe.pack()
        self.startG()
    def startG(self):    
        self.l1 = Label(self.lframe,text="Card Number",width=15,height=2);
        self.l1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=20)
        self.login = Button(self.lframe,text="Login", fg="black",height=2,width=20,command = self.login)
        self.login.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=50)

    def login(self):
            self.l1.destroy()
            self.login.destroy()
            self.l2 = Label(self.lframe,text="User ID  : ",height=2)
            self.l2.grid(row=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10)
            self.logout = Button(self.lframe, text="Logout !", fg="black",height=2,width=15,command = self.logout)
            self.logout.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=10,padx=10); 
    def logout(self):
        self.l2.destroy()
        self.logout.destroy()
        self.startG()              

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t  = Test()
    mainloop()
```

Above code snippet shows initial gui as 
[image: Final]
After clicking on login it changes to 
[image: Initial]
After clicking on logout GUI restore to initial GUI 
 [image: Final]
**Now login button is no more working .**

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming is the problem here. Try to rename method, widget names which are same. When you write `self.login` & `self.logout` both may be either class method or button. Just make sure to specify which is which by giving different names.